# Как сделать окно по ширине ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как сделать максимальную ширину окна по ширине ItemsControl.

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Frames}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="TotalCommander.MainWindow"
    ...
    Height="720" 
    Width="1280"
    MaxWidth={Binding ItemControl1.ActualWidth + ItemControl2.ActualWidth + ...}>
```

Типа того. Проблема в том, что, не получается взять длину элемента ItemControl. И совершенно непонятно как динамически менять ширину если добавится элемент.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хочу задать MaxWidth главного окна суммой длин элементов ItemsControl.

Comment: Дергать размер окна без согласия - глупо и очень будет бесить большинства пользователей. Представьте, если бы у вас стандартный проводник Windows изменял бы при каждом добавление нового файла свой размер, нравилось бы вам это?

Comment: напишите ковертер, поглядите, как это будет работать, создайте файл максимальной длины в каталоге - убедитесь, что выглядит убого если растянуть для него все окно, удалите конвертер

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я же не изменяю размер. Я хочу изменять максимальную возможную ширину. Чтоб нельзя было расширить окно и увидеть пустую часть окна.

Comment: `Чтоб нельзя было расширить окно и увидеть пустую часть окна` - для этого делают адаптивную верстку, где не окно подстраивается под элемент, а элемент под окно.

Comment: Указал SizeToContent="Width" для Windows. Ширина стала идеальной. Но хотелось бы привязать максимальную ширину к Width, но пока почему-то не получается

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Проблема решена установкой SizeToContent="Width" и ResizeMode="NoResize". Это может считаться костылем?)

Comment: Я вам свое мнение уже сказал по этой всей затеи. Окно должно быть определенных размеров уже изначально. Если мы делаем поддержку изменения размера, то тут должна быть поддержка "окна на весь экран" и макс. размер = разрешению экрана пользователя, а не какие то кастомные на размер контрола... Также работать надо не с окном, а с контролами, ибо они должны подгоняться под размер окна (а не окно под них), то есть меняем размер окна и наши контролы адаптируют свой размер (либо вовсе скрываются/изменяют вид). Что касается "костыля", то тут вы просто сделали не изменяемый размер окна, костыль - нет.

Comment: Соглашусь с @EvgeniyZ более правильный вариант подстраивать размер контролов под размер окна, а не наоборот. Исключение если вы делаете форму фиксированного размера. Ну а дальше вы задаете MinWidth для ваших ItemsControl, а по ширине даете им расползаться, чтобы они могли занять все свободное место. Для этого, я бы ширины столбцов в Grid (вы ведь в Grid их засовываете?) задавал через *.